# Set input value to null after closing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two inputs with open and close button, when i open the second input and enter value then remove it the value stays in the in the input it doesn't disappear, i tried something but it didn't work, here is my code:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#openInput').click(function() {
        $('.secondInput').toggle()
    });
});

$("#closeInput").click(function () {
    $('.secondInput').toggle();
    $('.secondInput').val('');
});
```

```css
.secondInput{
display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" />
<button type="button" id="openInput">Open</button><br>
<br>
<div class="secondInput">
<input type="text" class="form-control"/>
<button type="button" id="closeInput">Close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

- **$("#closeInput").click(function () {** is not wrapped inside the dom ready like the other
- you don't empty the input field but the div. Use: **$('.secondInput input').val('');** to solve the problem

```js
$(function() {
    $('#openInput').click(function() {
        $('.secondInput').toggle()
    });
    $("#closeInput").click(function () {
        $('.secondInput').toggle();
        $('.secondInput input').val('');
    });
});
```

```css
.secondInput {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" class="form-control"/>
<button type="button" id="openInput">Open</button>
<br>
<br>

<div class="secondInput">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    <button type="button" id="closeInput">Close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `children` method in order to `find` the input element from your div.

The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`, not `div`.

> children method gets the children of each element in the set of
>   matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Another method is to use it directly in the selector:

```
$('.secondInput input').val('');
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('#openInput').click(function() {
        $('.secondInput').toggle()
    });
    $("#closeInput").click(function () {
      $('.secondInput').toggle();
      $('.secondInput').children('input').val('');
    });
});
```

```css
.secondInput{
display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" />
<button type="button" id="openInput">Open</button><br>
<br>
<div class="secondInput">
<input type="text" class="form-control"/>
<button type="button" id="closeInput">Close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I added `id` attributes to your `<input type="text">` elements and then set their values to `''`.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#openInput').click(function() {
        $('.secondInput').toggle()
    });
});

$("#closeInput").click(function () {
    $('.secondInput').toggle();
    $('#firsttextinput, #secondtextinput').val('');
});
```

```css
.secondInput{
display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="firsttextinput" type="text" class="form-control" />
<button type="button" id="openInput">Open</button><br>
<br>
<div class="secondInput">
<input id="secondtextinput" type="text" class="form-control"/>
<button type="button" id="closeInput">Close</button>
</div>
```